# Android explode transition acts like slide transition

Tags: android-transitions

I am using beginTransitionDelayed with an Explode transition. The problem is that all the views slide in from 1 direction instead of coming in from different angles.

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        final RelativeLayout rootView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.createOfferSummary_rootView);
        final Explode explode = new Explode();
        explode.setDuration(1000)
               .setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(rootView, explode);
        rootView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}, 500);
```

This is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/createOfferSummary_rootView"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    tools:context="com.activities.CreateOfferSummaryActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:text="Contacts Selected:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:transitionGroup="true">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createOfferSummary_timeFrame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time Frame:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/createOfferSummary_location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:text="Location"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hey, were you able to resolve that? I am getting the same thing...

Comment: no. I was just playing around and never drilled down into the code to find a solution.

Comment: Couldn't fix that either. Seems like a condition with one of the other views I have...

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR try setting the start delay of your transition to zero

I ran into this issue because I set a delay on the explode transition, it looks like the propagation of the explode transition isn't delayed, and completes before the transition even starts. without propagation, an explode transition can look like a slide.